# What is the best way to handle large files in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build

I have a some very large files (some over 20k lines) containing a list of data. However when trying to build the appbundle, flutter keeps giving an out of memory error. I've noticed the issue occurs when a file is greater then 25k lines or if the lib folder is greater then 10MB.

I know I have enough ram as I have 2 computers (one with 16GB of ram and the other with 32GB) and upon removing a couple files it will build with 16GB of ram.

What is the best way to handle these large files so that I can build the appbundle without getting this error?

Comment: 20k lines of source code or asset data?

Comment: It's a dart file containing a long list of doubles.

Comment: i made a list with 50k lines of doubles and it works just fine, compiled on Linux 4GB machine

Comment: I have a number of these files totalling about 1.6 million lines, the largest of which is around 200k. I find that anything under 25k works until the lib folder exceeds 10MB.

Answer (score 0):

For Out of memory, It's works for me.

android >> gradle.properties

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M **to** org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M